# Error implementing phantomJS in splinter

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, splinter

I've tried implementing the following, passing along the path of phantomJS.exe installed in the system.

```
from splinter import Browser
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages\phantomJS\phantomJS.exe")
browser = Browser(driver)
browser.visit('www.google.com')
if browser.is_element_present_by_name('search'):
    print True
```

Unfortunately it throws me this error: `DriverNotFoundError: No driver for <selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver.WebDriver object at 0x000000000970A8D0>`

Whereas, as documented in splinter, I should be able to just use phantomJS by using `browser = Browser('phantomJS')`. This gives me `DriverNotFoundError: No driver for phantomJS'`

Can anyone point me out where I went wrong?

Comment: https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/drivers/phantomjs.html

Comment: Have you installed phantomjs to your machione first and added phantomjs binary to PATH (something like C:\PhantomJs\bin\phantomjs where the executable is)? Looks like you are using windows, so http://phantomjs.org/download.html . So if you will do everything correctly you should type "phantomjs --version" in your cmd and see the output

Comment: Thanks @Stanjer, I set it to path already. Apparently, I should have been using 'phantomjs' instead of 'phantomJS'. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with splinter and phantomjs. What worked for me was downloading phantomjs and adding it to the system path.

You can download phantomjs from [here](http://phantomjs.org/download.html).

After extracting the contents of the file, copy the location of phantomjs (or phantomjs.exe if working on windows, like me) and add it to your system path. Directions on adding a folder to window's PATH are [here](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path).

Hope this helped.